# How can I implement a default implementation of a generic trait for some generic type?

Tags: generics, rust, traits

I want to implement a default implementation of a trait `MovingAverage` over some generic type `Vec<T>`, but I'm obviously doing something wrong since I can make it work for the concrete type `Vec<f64>` but not for the concrete type `Vec<i32>`. Here's the output from the error:

```
error[E0599]: the method `sma` exists for struct `Vec<{integer}>`, but its trait bounds were not satisfied
   --> src/main.rs:8:22
    |
8   |     let smai = numsi.sma(n);
    |                      ^^^ method cannot be called on `Vec<{integer}>` due to unsatisfied trait bounds
    |
   ::: /home/czar/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/src/rust/library/alloc/src/vec/mod.rs:397:1
    |
397 | pub struct Vec<T, #[unstable(feature = "allocator_api", issue = "32838")] A: Allocator = Global> {
    | ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ doesn't satisfy `Vec<{integer}>: MovingAverage`
    |
    = note: the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
            `f64: AddAssign<{integer}>`
            which is required by `Vec<{integer}>: MovingAverage`
            `f64: SubAssign<{integer}>`
            which is required by `Vec<{integer}>: MovingAverage`
```

Here's my code from ma.rs:

```
pub trait MovingAverage<Output = Vec<f64>> {
    fn sma(&self, periods: usize) -> Output;
}

impl<T> MovingAverage for Vec<T>
where
    T: Copy + Num,
    f64: AddAssign<T> + SubAssign<T>,
{
    fn sma(&self, periods: usize) -> Vec<f64> {
        let mut sum = 0f64;
        let mut ma = Vec::<f64>::new();
        for i in 0..self.len() {
            if i >= periods {
                ma.push(sum / periods as f64);
                sum -= self[i - periods];
            }
            sum += self[i];
        }
        ma
    }
}
```

My main.rs

```
let numsf = vec![5., 10., 3., 9., 8., 7.];
let mut numsi = vec![2, 4, 3, 5, 1, 1];
let n = 2;
let smaf = numsf.sma(n);
let smai = numsi.sma(n); // doesnt work here
```

What's going on in my error, and what would be the proper way to go about implementing a trait over a generic type without having to implement the trait for each concrete type? Thanks in advance, and kindly let me know if you need any further clarification.

Comment: The error says there is no add-assign for `f64` from an integer. This [doesn't compile](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=4216416227c6800334e36772af34ad8b): `let mut n: f64 = 1.0; n += 1;` Same for sub-assign.

Comment: Which crate do you use for "Num" in your code?
`f64: AddAssign<T> + SubAssign<T>` - this constraint doesn't make sense. You can put constraints on generic types, but f64 is concrete (not generic). Try to remove this constraint, and see what compiler produces.

Comment: I'm getting this error when removing the constraint
```
  --> src/ma.rs:15:21
   |
15 |                 sum -= self[i - periods];
   |                     ^^ no implementation for `f64 -= T`
   |
   = help: the trait `SubAssign<T>` is not implemented for `f64`
help: consider extending the `where` bound, but there might be an alternative better way to express this requirement
```

Comment: The error is because I'm trying to do `sum -= self[i - periods]`. The output from the compiler: the trait `SubAssign<T>` is not implemented for `f64`. Here `sum` is an `f64` and `self` is a `T`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe a better bound would be `T: Into<f64>`. Then you can simply convert each element into a `f64` when you access it. Also, if you implement the trait for `[T]` instead of `Vec<T>`, it will also work for slices. Try this:

```rust
impl<T: Copy + Into<f64>> MovingAverage for [T] {
    fn sma(&self, periods: usize) -> Vec<f64> {
        let mut sum = 0f64;
        let mut ma = Vec::<f64>::new();
        for i in 0..self.len() {
            if i >= periods {
                ma.push(sum / periods as f64);
                sum -= self[i - periods].into();
            }
            sum += self[i].into();
        }
        ma
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=6b1233bf0e2a421d1b5e0343c3e6a8df)

(Side note: I think your code may unintentionally ignore the last element of the input)

Comment: Yes, this works and was exactly what I was trying to do. Thank you.

Comment: Glad I could help! :) Be sure to mark the answer as accepted so others know the question has been answered. (And see my note about missing the last element)